# Объвление переменной в запросе

Tags: postgresql

Выполняю запрос, в котором несколько раз встречается одна и та же функция с одними и теми же параметрами. Например:

```
SELECT sum($1, $2) AS total, sum($1, $2) AS amount, sum($1, $2) AS result ...
```

Возможно ли записать результат выполнения в некую переменную, чтобы не выполнять расчёт суммы каждый раз? Например, насколько я знаю, в MSSQL возможно следующее решение:

```
DECLARE @total INT
SET @total = SUM(1, 2)
```

Как сделать подобный запрос в PostgreSQL? Функция `sum()` приведена лишь для примера. На самом деле там каждый раз выполняется более "тяжёлая" функция и хотелось бы оптимизировать этот момент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предположу, что в большинстве случаев планировщик *PostgreSQL*
достаточно умён, чтобы понять, что чистые функции для одних и тех же
данных будут выдавать один и тот же результат.  Но если вам так уж надо,
просто заверните всё в подзапрос:

```sql
SELECT n AS total
     , n AS amount
     , n AS result
     , /* … */
  FROM
  (
    SELECT SUM(/* … */) AS n
      FROM /* … */
  ) AS t(n)
;
```

Comment: Как по вашему мнению, функция `plainto_tsquery()` является "чистой" и стоит оставить эту работу планировщику или всё же лучше прописывать запрос явно, как в вашем ответе?

Comment: Я бы сказал, что да, но лучше на всякий случай побенчить.